# Is there a Ruby library that can put an array of arrays into a ascii table?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a Ruby library that will task an array of arrays (like the CSV does) and outputs a string that displays the data in an ASCII table like this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| route_id | route_color |
+----------+-------------+
| 01-1079  | FFFF7C      |
| 04-1079  | FFFF7C      |
+----------+-------------+
```

Is such a thing available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/visionmedia/terminal-table (Gem at http://rubygems.org/gems/terminal-table)

This library appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi @dylan does it have the option to do multiple columns with in a single column ? I am intending to have a column header with 3 small columns under it

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tj/terminal-table is cool for handling ASCII in the console.

You can try this:

```
require 'terminal-table/import'

puts table(['route_id', 'route_color'], ["01-1079", "FFFF7C"], ["04-1079" , "FFFF7C"])
```

And the result is should be:

```
+----------+-------------+
| route_id | route_color |
+----------+-------------+
| 01-1079  | FFFF7C      |
| 04-1079  | FFFF7C      |
+----------+-------------+
```